# Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio's find (Ctrl+F) from searching through certain directories in the solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've included a huge open source javascript framework that has thousands of files in it into my solution. It would be nice to include only what I need, but the classes are interdependent, and not in an obvious way either. These files really slow down the find option in VS 2013 just because there are so many of them.

Anyhow, these files are all in one directory. Right now, I just search 'current project', 'current document', or 'all open documents' if/because that option doesn't contain the huge directory. But I miss using 'entire solution' especially because I have so many projects in it now.

It would be worth my while to add this huge directory to a do-not-search list if such a thing exists. Does it exist?

Comment: I just decided to exclude the files from the project for now, I can still step through them anyway and the debug site can find them. I'm not sure if I can set breakpoints, but I doubt I'd ever edit the library code anyway.

Comment: Still curious if I can exclude from the search, though!